# ReactJS: getImageData from image passed via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React, please, help me to understand why this approach fails.
I have an `<Some />` component in my App.js file, with `<img>` tag inside.

```
 <Some class="grade-wrapper">
       <img src={imageUrl}/>
 </Some>
```

in `<Some />` component file i want to get that image, and draw canvas like this

```
render() {
    const getImageData = (image) => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const size = 10;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, size, size);
        const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, size, size).data;
    };
    const img = this.props.children
    console.warn(getImageData(img))
    return (null)
}
```

but it fails with error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

I think this issue, because in `this.props.children` I got React element instead of html image element.
Is this possible to getImageData when image passing through props?

Also, I think that image hasn't been loaded yet when I call drawImage...

Without react it's look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2z1c7zym/7/)

Comment: class should be className but its not the issue also you cant return an empty div in react

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Thanks, class is prop for custom component, I think I can use it?

Comment: `this.props.children` is **not** a `HTMLImageElement` as you'd expect. It is a React component.

Comment: @CroaToa i sugest you start by reading some basic stuff about react because your code has nothing to do with react

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif ok sir, as you say